# file input does not update except in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, setinterval

I have a local program which writes a JSON object to a file so that a JavaScript can pick up its data and process it. The file is selected using an `<input>` object:

```
<form id = "getfiles">
    <input type = "file" multiple id = "files" />
</form>
```

with the following JS function `setInterval` to repeat every 300ms. However, when the file changes, only Google Chrome reloads the file and processes the new content; I have to manually reselect the file on the page in IE 10 and Firefox 20.

```
function speakText() 
{
    var thefile = document.getElementById('files').files[0];
    var lastChanged = thefile.lastModifiedDate;
    var reader = new FileReader();               

    reader.onload = function(event)
    {
        var lcd = document.getElementById("last_change_date");
        if (!lcd)
        {
            var spanLastChanged = document.createElement("span");
            spanLastChanged.id = "last_change_date";
            spanLastChanged.innerText = lastChanged;
            console.log(lastChanged);
            document.body.appendChild(spanLastChanged);
        }
        else
        {
            // compare lastChanged with last_change_date
            var last_known_change = Date.parse(lcd.innerText);
            // var last_known_change = Date.parse(thefile.lastModifiedDate);
            if (last_known_change !== Date.parse(lastChanged))
            {
                console.log("Something is new since " + lcd.innerText);
                var fileContent = event.target.result;
                var commands = JSON.parse(fileContent);
                handleJSON(fileContent);
                lcd.innerText = lastChanged;
            }
        }
    }
    reader.readAsText(thefile, "UTF-8"); 
}
```

Comment: @icodebuster Please do not try to justify a frivolous edit with space trickery. Given that I'd already enclosed a HTML element in `code` formatting, formatting "JSON object" and "JavaScript" as code would not help much, and in fact add ambiguity to the use of that particular format. Also, please learn to use a semicolon; the replacement of a comma is inappropriate in that context.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox and IE are doing the right thing per spec: the File objects associated with a file input are supposed to be immutable snapshots of a file at the point when the File object was created.  It's a known bug in WebKit/Blink that they just store a reference to the file's data, so that mutating the data will change what the File object sees.

In fact, the WebKit/Blink behavior is a privacy bug: when a user selects a file in a file input, they are giving a web page permission to read the data of the file *at that time*, not for all future versions of the file!  Which is why the spec is written as it is.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, definitely worth my +1. I'm going to have to remodel this transaction then :/